# Writing a function to produce a Kaplan-Meier curve

Tags: r, function, survival-analysis

I am trying to write a function that spits out a KM survival curve. I am going to use this in a ShineyApp which is why I want to write a function so I can easily pass in arguments from a dropdown menu (which will input as a string into the `strata` argument). Here is a simplified version of what I need:

```
survival_function <- function(data_x, strata_x="1"){
  
survFormula <- Surv(data_x$time, data_x$status)
my_survfit <- survfit(data=data_x, as.formula(paste("survFormula~", {{strata_x}})))
ggsurvplot(my_survfit, data = data_x, pval=T)
  
}

survival_function(inputdata, "strata_var")
```

I get an error:
`Error in paste("survFormula1~", { : object 'strata_x' not found`

I'm at a loss because
`as.formula(paste("~", {{arg}}))`
has worked in other functions I've written to produce plots using ggplot to easily change variables to facet by, but this doesn't even seem to recognize `strata_x` as an argument.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  However, here you appear to be using data masking (because you are *embrac*ing `strata_x` in `{{` and `}}` but passing a character as the value of `strata_x`.  That appears contradictory.  Without a minimal reproducible example it's difficult to say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs a couple of tweaks to get it working with `ggsurvplot`. It would be best to create the `Surv` object as a new column in the data frame and use this column in your formula. You also need to make sure you have an actual symbolic formula as the `$call$formula` member of the `survfit` object, otherwise `ggsurvplot` will fail to work due to non-standard evaluation deep within its internals.

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

survival_function <- function(data_x, strata_x) {
  
  data_x$s <- Surv(data_x$time, data_x$status)
  survFormula <- as.formula(paste("s ~", strata_x))
  my_survfit <- survfit(survFormula, data = data_x)
  my_survfit$call$formula <- survFormula
  ggsurvplot(my_survfit, data = data_x)

}
```

We can test this on the included `lung` data set:

```r
survival_function(lung, "sex")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Allan, that did the trick. Thank you!